# I'm getting the following error : others/dataTables.bootstrap.less' wasn't found

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gulp-less

This is my gulpfile. I don't know what is going on with this. as it worked before in my other project. is something outdated or something?

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
    var rename = require('gulp-rename');
    var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');



    gulp.task("copyfiles", function(){
        // Copy jQuery, Bootstrap, and FontAwesome
        gulp.src("vendor/bower_dl/jquery/dist/jquery.js")
            .pipe(gulp.dest("resources/assets/js/"));

        gulp.src("vendor/bower_dl/bootstrap/less/**")
            .pipe(gulp.dest("resources/assets/less/bootstrap"));

        gulp.src("vendor/bower_dl/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js")
            .pipe(gulp.dest("resources/assets/js/"));

        gulp.src("vendor/bower_dl/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**")
            .pipe(gulp.dest("public/assets/fonts"));

        gulp.src("vendor/bower_dl/fontawesome/less/**")
            .pipe(gulp.dest("resources/assets/less/fontawesome"));

        gulp.src("vendor/bower_dl/fontawesome/fonts/**")
            .pipe(gulp.dest("public/assets/fonts"));

        // Copy datatables
        var dtDir = 'vendor/bower_dl/datatables-plugins/integration/';

        gulp.src("vendor/bower_dl/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js")//-----
            .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/js/'));

        gulp.src(dtDir + 'bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css')
            .pipe(rename('dataTables.bootstrap.less'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/less/others/'));//-----

        gulp.src(dtDir + 'bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/js/'));

    });


    /**
     * Default gulp is to run this elixir stuff
     */
    elixir(function(mix) {
        // Combine scripts
        mix.scripts([
                'js/jquery.js',
                'js/bootstrap.js',
                'js/jquery.dataTables.js',
                'js/dataTables.bootstrap.js'
            ],
            'public/assets/js/admin.js',
            'resources/assets'
        );
        // Compile Less
        mix.less('admin.less', 'public/assets/css/admin.css');
    });
```

I dont know why this is happening. I'm following the tutorial to a tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first had to run "gulp copyfiles", Then I had to run gulp again with no arguments

so first run

```
 gulp copyfiles
```

then run

```
gulp
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you did not install the dependency in your new project. Perhaps run a bower install in the root directory. And make sure the bower file has the bootstrap datatables plugin listed in plugins required.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and encountered the same problem.

I did run gulp copyfiles, but dataTables.bootstrap.css and dataTables.bootstrap.js were just not copied.

I resolved this problem by manually copying the two files and renaming the css to less.